# Coordinate Geometry

Tags: geometry

2. Parallelogram ABCD

Determine the coordinates of the unknown vertex or vertices of each figure below. Use variables if necessary.I'm not sure how to find C and E. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer of $C$ on the piece of paper. The vertical coordinate is the same as that of $D$ and since $ABCD$ is a parallellogram, $AB=CD$. Since both $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel to the $x$-axis, the $x$-coordinate of $C$ has to be the length of $AB$+ the $x$-coordinate of $D$, i.e. $C=(a+b,c)$.

The point $E$ is somewhat trickier. It is exactly halfway between pairwise opposite sides of the parallellogram. That is to say, if we draw a line parallel to $AB$ through $E$, this line is as far from $AB$ as it is from $CD$. From this, the $y$-coordinate of $E$ can be calculated as $\frac{c}{2}$. In the same way, a line parallel to $AD$ through $E$ is as far from $AD$ as it is from $BC$. The intersection of this new line with $AB$ is at the point $(\frac{a}{2},0)$ and that with $CD$ can be found in a similar fashion to $C$, namely $(b+\frac{a}{2},c)$. The $x$-coordinate of $E$ has to be the mean of these two $x$-values. (Can you see why?) As a result, $E=(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{c}{2})$.

Comment: I don't understand how a+b=x-coordinate of C?

Comment: What's the distance between $B$ and $A$ along the $x$-axis? This should be $a$. Now what's the distance between $C$ and $D$ along the $x$-axis? Since $ABCD$ is a parallellogram, it's the same, so $a$ as well. Now, the $x$-coordinate of $D$ is $b$, and so the $x$-coordinate of $C$ is...

Answer (score 0):

Opposite sides of a parallelogram are parallel and congruent.  Since $\overline{AB}$ lies on the x-axis, it is horizontal.  Thus, side $\overline{CD}$ is also horizontal.  Since it passes through the point $D(b, c)$, the $y$-coordinate of point $C$ is $c$.  Since $\overline{AB}$ has length $a$, so does $\overline{CD}$.  Hence, the $x$-coordinate of point $C$ is $a + b$.  Therefore, the coordinates of point $C$ are $(a + b, c)$.

The diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.  Thus, point $E$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AC}$.  Hence, its coordinates are

$$\left(\frac{a + b}{2}, \frac{c}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I don't understand how a+b=x-coordinate of C?

Comment: Since $\overline{AB}$ has length $a$, you add $a$ to the $x$-coordinate of $B$ to obtain $b + a = a + b$ for the $x$-coordinate of $C$.